# Help Troubleshooting L298n connected to dc motor

Tags: motor, l298n

I am relatively new to Arduino, and I am trying to power a DC motor with the L298N dual H-Bridge. I have done as follows:
I am powering everything with the Arduino that is connected to the PC. (I know this isn't ideal, but I don't have a better power supply yet)
I connected the 5V output from Arduino to the 12V terminal of the L298N, and connected it to the Arduino ground. The red light from the L298N shines brightly.
Then, I connected the IN3 and IN4 pins to the Arduino digital pins 7 and 8, respectively.
Finally, I connected the Out 3 and Out 4 to my DC motor, but it doesn't turn at all. I use the following code:

```cpp
int In3=7; 
int In4=8; //idem para In2

void setup() {
  pinMode(In3,OUTPUT); //avisa que nuestros pines son todos outputs
  pinMode(In4,OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(In3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(In4,LOW); 
}

void loop() {

}
```

For the time being I decided to not use the PWM, so that I can start simple. I tried changing all cables and even the motor, but it just won't rotate. The L298N is brand new, so it's unlikely that it is damaged. What could I try next?

Comment: Welcome to Arduino! Please take the [tour](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Note that *(SOLVED)* tags should not be edited into the question's title, please "accept" the correct answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had the jumper disconnected from the ENB pins, which immediately solved the problem when I reconnected it, so it is now fixed!

Comment: It's OK to accept your own answer as the solution to the problem. I think you get 15 rep for it.